# WPF: Custom control property was already registered by another custom control error

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I created two custom controls that are exactly the same except that they are of two different types.

ControlOne

```
public class ControlOne : TextEdit
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AwesomeSauceProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("AwesomeSauce", typeof(string), typeof(FormTextEditInput));           

        public string AwesomeSauce
        {
            get { return GetValue(AwesomeSauceProperty) as string; }
            set { SetValue(AwesomeSauceProperty, value); }
        }

    }
```

ControlTwo

```
public class ControlTwo : PasswordEdit
        {
            public static readonly DependencyProperty AwesomeSauceProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("AwesomeSauce", typeof(string), typeof(FormTextEditInput));           

            public string AwesomeSauce
            {
                get { return GetValue(AwesomeSauceProperty) as string; }
                set { SetValue(AwesomeSauceProperty, value); }
            }

        }
```

And in XAML i simply do this

```
<controls:ControlOne AwesomeSauce="Yummy"/>
<controls:ControlTwo AwesomeSauce="Tummy"/>
```

and I get error

```
System.ArgumentException
'AwesomeSauce' property was already registered by 'ControlOne'.
```

You may be asking why I need two controls that do the same things, I can just create Data Templates and move on. But I want to be stubborn and say that I need custom controls of different types that do the same thing. It be nice if I could use custom controls of a generic type, but I found out that that is not possible (right?).

I also don't want to use different names because that would just be a hack to the problem.

I just want my two controls to be able to use the same names for their dependency properties. Is there something I'm missing here? or I'm I just flat out not allowed to use the same names?

I'm guessing that attached properties would be the solution for this, but I really want to push for a custom control.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The third parameter `ownerType` of the `DependencyProperty.Register` method must be the type of the class that registers the property, i.e. ControlOne and ControlTwo in your case:

```
public class ControlOne : TextEdit
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AwesomeSauceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AwesomeSauce", typeof(string), typeof(ControlOne));
    ...
}

public class ControlTwo : TextEdit
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AwesomeSauceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AwesomeSauce", typeof(string), typeof(ControlTwo));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

aside from the accepted answer which is correct for this situation, in some ocassaions it's maybe because you're not registering your property `static`, a `DependencyProperty` is not always dependent to `DependencyObject`, for instance you may are building a `DependencyObject` with a propery like `DepObj.DepProp = "some prop"` but the `DependencyObject` has not built yet, so `DependencyProperty`s must always be `static` (and which is `public static` should be `readonly` too due to programming logic ;))

wrong declaration of a DependencyProperty:

```
public DependencyProperty CProp = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "a",
            typeof(B),
            typeof(C),
            new PropertyMetadata(new C() { a= "default" }, CPropCallBack)
        );
```

correct declaration of a dependencyProperty:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CProp = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "a",
            typeof(B),
            typeof(C),
            new PropertyMetadata(new C() { a= "default" }, CPropCallBack)
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

same just happens to me, but with only one UserControl: "Vista.xaml" that is created multiple times into several tab pages of my main window.

I discover there is a lot of relations between the name of the property, the name of the variables and the other names across the app.

So i have to avoid name collisions across xaml Style, Code Behind, vars, funcs, etc. And that solve the problem for me.

this is the control in my "MainWindow.xaml"

```
<local:Vista Margin="8,10,10,0" Titulo="Here goes title"/>
```

this is the label inside my custom control "Vista" that shows the title set by the property "Titulo"

```
Codigo: 

  <Label x:Name="labelTitulo" Content="{Binding ElementName=ControlVista, 
  Path=Titulo}" Style="{StaticResource estiloTituloVista}" />

//////////
```

Here is the property wich is located in UserControl code-behind "Vista.xaml.cs"

```
enter code here
       public static readonly DependencyProperty TituloProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register
            (
                "Titulo",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(Vista),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("")
            );
        public string Titulo
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TituloProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TituloProperty, value); }
        }

enter code here
```

Which goes just before the main class of your UserControl

```html
  public Vista()
     {
       InitializeComponent();

       if (Titulo != null && Titulo != "") { labelTitulo.Content = Titulo; }
           
     }
```

You have to name your UserControl in order to assign the property to one of it's childs.

in my case i named it "ControlVista"

This name is binding with the *Content* property of child label control "labelTitulo"

[View of Vista.xaml design mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhyLH.png)

[This is how it looks in the mainwindow.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZNsj.png)